# What is causing tiny new growth to die?

Tags: diseases, pests, growth, peppers, chili

I have a young Jalapeno and its new growth is dead looking. It has tiny leaves and its flowers are dead and brown. I looked using a jewelry loupe and could not see any pests.

[image: Close up of dead growth]

[image: Young Jalapeno]

Comment: How much light per day? Looks mulched so do You water it rarely enough(1/week)?